# Choose a color with probability proportionate to its weight in a group of colors

Tags: ruby, interview-questions, random

Input: An array of colors with weights. e.g `[['red', 10], ['blue', 20], ['green', 30]]`

Output: A random color from the array, based on it's proportion to the other colors. So for the example above, red should show up 1/6 of the time, blue 2/6, green 3/6.

I was asked this during an interview. After talking to that interviewer I went from an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution to this, which runs in O(n). I feel like there should be a better way?

```
def random_color(colors_with_weights)
  probabilities = {}
  count = 0
  colors_with_weights.each do |color_weight|
    probabilities[count..count+color_weight[1]] = color_weight[0]
    count = count + color_weight[1]
  end
  random_number = rand(count)
  random_range = probabilities.keys.find { |k| k.include?(random_number) }
  probabilities[random_range]
end

colors_with_weights = [['red', 10], ['blue', 20], ['green', 30]]
puts random_color(colors_with_weights)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a better algorithm.  There is a minor bug, though: you are using inclusive-inclusive ranges, when they should be inclusive-exclusive ranges.  That means that you've overweighted red by \$\frac{1}{60}\$ and underweighted green by \$\frac{1}{60}\$.

The way it the algorithm is expressed could be tweaked a bit.

- The `count` isn't counting elements; it's more of a `sum`.
- The block could accept two parameters `|color, weight|` to automatically destructure `|color_weight|`.
- The hash isn't really being used for a lookup, so I would just keep it as an array.

```
def random_color(colors_with_weights)
  sum = 0
  colors_with_cumul_weights = colors_with_weights.collect do |color, weight|
    [color, sum ... (sum += weight)]
  end
  rand_num = rand(sum)
  colors_with_cumul_weights.find { |color, range| range === rand_num }.first
end
```

In an interview situation, I'd just accept your code as a fine answer.

Comment: nice catch with the inclusive / exclusive

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it up a bit this way:

```
def random_color(weighted_colors)
  total = weighted_colors.transpose.last.reduce(:+)
  random = rand(total)
  weighted_colors.find {|x| (random -= x.last) && (random < 0)}.first
end
```

Or, if your moral code permits the wanton murder of RAM, you can really have some fun:

```
def random_color(weighted_colors)
  weighted_colors.flat_map {|x| [x.first] * x.last}.sample
end
```

Comment: My first stab (brute force) at it was a longer version of your infinite RAM solution.

Comment: I tried to get a pure functional, 1 statement version of the first algorithm, but wasn't able to do it :(  I still feel it's possible....